# Load Balancer to Apache instances. Should I use Persistence connections to minimize timed out apache instances?

Tags: apache, load, persistence, persistent

I was trying to figure out if using *persistence* on my load balancer would allow for better utilization of apache spawned processes if paired with *persistent* Apache configurations.

My thinking is that without *persistence* on the load balancer, a user could end up on any of the servers, while an instance of Apache spawned would take some time to die being idle.  If I routed that same connection through to the same Apache process with *persistent*, then there is little wasted cpu on idle connections from the load balancer switching to another server.

Or am I seeing this wrong?

(here is a good article explaining the difference between *persistent* and *persistence*  http://devcentral.f5.com/weblogs/macvittie/archive/2008/07/11/3443.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could enable sticky sessions on the load balancer (IP-based) so that the persistent connections aren't created on multiple apache instances.

Also, if there's a firewall between your Apache servers and your app-tier, you would want to match the firewall's timeout on your connection.

Comment: I know it can be done.  The question is about efficiencies and processor savings.  Does the time-out for the apache instance leave lingering (un-used) instances that are waiting for a connection if you have a round-robin load balancer and a non-persistent httpd?

Comment: The timeout is on the socket level, to ensure idle connections are closed. If the socket inactive for too long, the socket is closed and a new one is created if needed. If not, you save on the overhead of creating a new socket. When httpd is non-persistent, the connection is created from scratch every time so it doesn't matter if the LB's VIP is sticky. LB persistence provides a performance boost primarily when the httpd connections are pooled/persistent. You may require persistance on the VIP independent of the httpd settings if these requests aren't stateless.